# Flagged comment indentation

Tags: bug, comments, comment-flags

I have flagged a comment as non-constructive and noticed that an odd indentation has been added on the left of it.

> [image: Notice the comment indentation]

I assumed that this is to do with the red flag displaying on hover (that indicates the comment has been flagged). However, the indentation persisted when I accessed the same question via incognito windows (without being logged in).

Is this intentional? A bug?

PS. I'm using Chrome/43.0.2357.130 on Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Looks like there is a `<td class=' comment-score'>` with two non-breaking white spaces appended to the DOM (comment's `<tr>` being a distant ancestor).

Comment: No repro. Does it happen with other comments?

Comment: Just flagged your comment to test (sorry!) and the issue does not exist. I have looked at the HTML and looks [the same](https://imgur.com/fifDLIy)

Comment: Well, I see all comments "jump" a bit to the right when clicking the flag icon,  but then jump back to the proper place after a second. And it doesn't "stick", so still not sure what happened in your case.